# python code incorrect. Not meeting the requirements listed

Tags: python

This is for my computer science class and I dont make the criteria.
The idea is: Write a function named print_sum that accepts three numbers as parameters and prints the sum. First, write the print_sum function. Then, prompt the user for three inputs, and call your print_sum function on those inputs.
I write:

```
def print_sum(a, b, c):
  print('The sum:', int(a) + int(b) + int(c))
a = input('Enter the 1st number: ')
b = input('Enter the 2nd number: ')
c = input('Enter the 3rd number: ')
print_sum(a, b, c)
```

I do not meet the criteria: Check that the function is using the 3 parameters passed to it rather than the 3 inputs directly.

anyone able to correct what I am doing wrong? should be simple but I cannot figure it out

Comment: I don't see a problem with what you have. `print_sum` itself *does* only use the arguments it receives; it doesn't know anything about where they came from.

Answer (score 3):

While I think the clarity of the feedback you got is abhorrent at best, the reason this check is failing is likely because you've named your variables the same in both the scope of the function and the global scope.

As such, if you name them differently, you'll probably pass the check you referenced:

```
def print_sum(first, second, third):
  print('The sum:', int(first) + int(second) + int(third))
a = input('Enter the 1st number: ')
b = input('Enter the 2nd number: ')
c = input('Enter the 3rd number: ')
print_sum(a, b, c)
```

Comment: It isn't necessarily run by my instructor its a website that has the course on it

Comment: I would have thought it was print_sum’s use of int: the spec indicates that print_sum assumes it’s inputs are numbers, so the int should go elsewhere (eg, the caller)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble - on the first pass, I thought the same. However I think the subtle hint there was that the question referred to "number", with a lowercase "n" - if they were looking to students to properly typecast the arguments they're passing in I would imagine the only fair way to ask for that would be to capitalize the "N" in "number".